# How to keep a copy of the deleted rows as archive before deleting?

Tags: mysql, logging, data-warehouse, database-administration

I have designed a table which will be used for log purpose. This is the table structure and I will use MySQL (InnoDB engine) and it will be hosted in AWS RDS.

```
| id (primary_key auto_increment) | entity_id (foreign key) | previous_value | current_value | calculation_done_with_this_row (boolean) | created_time |
```

This table will be also used for some critical business calculations and **as soon as the calculation is done for a certain day the log table's data is no more needed.** So as of now, I planned to  **delete** the data from the log table as soon as the calculation is done for such rows.

But my concern is that if something goes wrong and I need to look into the historical data what will I do then? As I am deleting the records I won't have anything to back me up for such situations? On the other hand, if I won't delete the data from the log table it will be full of unnecessary data that won't contribute to the business calculations; thus slowing down the performance of the calculation query.

My requirements is to keep the log table size small and also keep the unnecessary logs for future reference as historical data and also import the historical data back to the main database if needed.

Comment: Possibilities 1) write the rows to another table as part of the delete. 2) Backup the table before doing the delete, give it a name that reflects the date the data was for. Restore it to another table name, if you need to check something.

Comment: I'd keep a table with just the data you need for calculation and after the calculation I'd move them to a log table where they will stay for reference. This log table for what you say will never (or almost never) be used so you don't have to bother for performance (even if it will be fully operative in case of need).

Comment: Did you check [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-types.html)? This is exact the concept to keep the current data small (with partition pruning) and effectively remove older data (drop partition).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber I tried to do the partitioning. But later on, found that partitioning in a table that has foreign key restrictions in InnoDB engine is not yet supported. And my log table happens to have one foreign key reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the few cases where `PARTITIONing` is useful.

Change the table to be `PARTITION BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(...))`.  Add a new partition each night; drop really old partitions when you feel there is no chance to need them.

More details:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint .  Also you might be interested in summarization techniques: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

Comment: I am using the InnoDB engine For Mysql. And my table has one foreign key reference. And Sadly, InnoDB doesn't allow partitioning a table that has a foreign key constraint. :(

Comment: @T4puSD - Are you actually using FKs for anything other than the index they generate?  Indexes are available (but should be revisited) when adding Partitioning.

Comment: I am not clear what you are tyring to say. But my table does have one foreign key which references another table's id. And as per the documentation provided by [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations-storage-engines.html#:~:text=InnoDB%20storage%20engine.,foreign%20keys%20cannot%20be%20partitioned)  InnoDB doesn't support such table partitioning.

Comment: @T4puSD - Correct, `PARTITIONing` does not allow for FKs in either direction.  Can you do without the FK?  And have a suitable `INDEX` to provide the lookup efficiency that the FK provides.  You lose the integrity check and the ability to have `CASCADEing` actions.

Comment: I can't drop the foreign key constraint from the table. I am not allowed to do so. Initially, I also wanted to go with partitioning but because of the foreign key issue, I am trying to find other solutions.

Comment: @T4puSD - "can't drop the foreign key constraint" -- ??  Is your boss not allowing it?  Or what?